# Python: How to open a folder on Windows Explorer(Python 3.6.2, Windows 10)

Tags: windows, python-3.x, operating-system, windows-10, windows-explorer

If I store the path that i want to open in a string called finalpath which looks something like this:
"./2.8 Movies/English/Die Hard Series"

then how do i open this in Windows Explorer?(Windows 10)(Python 3.6.2)

P.S I know many people have asked this question but I did not find them clear. Please answer soon.

Comment: Edit queue is full unfortunately.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I found a simple method.

```
import os
path = "C:/Users"
path = os.path.realpath(path)
os.startfile(path)
```

Comment: Note that `startfile` is Windows only.

Comment: True, but notice that the OP specifically tagged Windows and Windows-10. For platform independency you can consider [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54641180/4575793).

Answer (score 17):

Other alternatives

```
import webbrowser, os
path="C:/Users"
webbrowser.open(os.path.realpath(path))
```

or with os alone

```
import os
os.system(f'start {os.path.realpath(path)}')
```

or subprocess

```
import subprocess,os
subprocess.Popen(f'explorer {os.path.realpath(path)}')
```

or

```
subprocess.run(['explorer', os.path.realpath(path)])
```

Comment: `webbrowser` also works in Linux; unlike other methods. For `subprocess`, it will be `open`, `xdg-open` or `explorer`, depending on the OS.

Comment: Already mentioned in [this underrated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54641180/4575793)

Answer (score 13):

Cross platform:

```py
import webbrowser


path = 'C:/Users'

webbrowser.open('file:///' + path)
```

Comment: [Note that on some platforms, trying to open a filename using this function, may work and start the operating system’s associated program. However, this is neither supported nor portable.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.open)

Answer (score 0):

Windows:

```
import os
path = r'C:\yourpath'
os.startfile(path)
```

This method is a simplified version of the approved answer.

Answer (score -4):

```
import os

path = "C:\\Users"


def listdir(dir):
    filenames = os.listdir(dir)
    for files in filenames:
        print(files)


listdir(path)
```

ok here is another piece of cake it list all your files in a directory