# Attempting to prompt directory selection menu

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, savefiledialog, filedialog

So, in the code below, I'm attempting to ensure that when I press a button that says "Select File", a window pops up that lets you choose a folder/file to save some information in that will be stored into the program later. The code is below:

```
def selectFile():
        file = filedialog.askopenfile(defaultextension='.*',
                                        filetypes=[
                                            ("Text file", ".txt"),
                                            ("HTML file", ".html"),
                                            ("All files", ".*"),
                                            ("Word files", ".docx")
                                        ])
        if file:
            storedFile = file
            print(storedFile)
        if file is None:
            return
```

This code I've written for a prior program is asking to open a certain file of either txt, html, or docx filetype -- but I'm struggling finding out how to adjust it to open folder selection window.

The new program I'm making should, in theory, be able to download all email attachments from a specific gmail label automatically to a folder on your desktop. Hopefully I can get this going!

Comment: Why are you using `askopenfile`? Most of the time, using `askopenfilename` is better. Also there is `filedialog.askdirectory` which is what you are after.

Comment: What stops you from using `os.system(f'start {path}')` ?. `path` should be a directory though.

Comment: I'm not fully aware of all the different things you can do in python with libraries and such. I'm still very much a "YouTube & Go" programmer -- hoping to learn a lot! I'll test around with `filedialog.askdirectory` and see what I can come up with.

EDIT -- wow, that was super easy. It's crazy how much knowing a different method from a library can help. It works now -- thanks again lizard.

Cheers, Lizzard!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: How to open a folder on Windows Explorer(Python 3.6.2, Windows 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47812372/python-how-to-open-a-folder-on-windows-explorerpython-3-6-2-windows-10)

Comment: sometimes it may help to just look at the docs, tutorials usually cover only the basis and rarely all the available methods so searching google for docs may help in such situations

Comment: @Matiiss -- I'll definitely start digging into some documentation for the libraries. That's a solid idea.

Comment: @Spitball So is your questions answered

Comment: @CoolCloud yes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use a GUI to open a directory in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22380272/how-do-i-use-a-gui-to-open-a-directory-in-python-3)

Comment: Then go ahead and delete this question or give your own answer

Answer (score 0):

`filedialog.askdirectory` works in this instance -- it was an issue of not knowing the documentation and usage of the proper code.